# setting up pycharm to work with remote django project

Tags: django, pycharm

I'm new to django. I inherit a project sitting on a remote server running redhat and apache. How do i debug this project using pycharm? 
i can't seem to figure out the right way to do this. Could someone point me to a right direction?

what's the right step?

Comment: did you try running the project locally? I assume the project is running in prod but you might not want to change your stuff directly there.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html?

Comment: You can also combine nnaelle's and Daniel Robinson's suggestions. Install redhat and apache in a virtual machine and use a remote interpreter to debug it. Pycharm works well with Vagrant.